# The password supplied is invalid. Passwords must conform to the password strength requirements configured for the default provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, passwords, migration

How to prevent that error?

> The password supplied is invalid.  Passwords must conform to the
>   password strength requirements configured for the default provider.

I do migration users from the old ASP website to a new ASP .NET MVC 4 Website.

```
var newUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(oldUser.Login, oldUser.Password, userEMail);
```

**web.config**

```
 <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add connectionStringName="MembershipConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
             enablePasswordReset="true" 
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" 
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" 
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" 
             minRequiredPasswordLength="3" 
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
             applicationName="MyCoolApplication" 
             name="DefaultMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

And it seems I need correct solution for some users who have incorrect password.

How I can manage it in a proper way?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check wich passwords fail? Maybe there are one or two character passwords?

Comment: @StephanB Yeah...Exactly...

Comment: Well, set minRequiredPasswordLength to 1 and hit it, what did I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that you are using the same .NET MVC version. Why not skip C#, use the SQL knowledge we got from school?

```
Insert into [newDB].[table] (columns)
select [oldDB].[table].[columns]
from [newDB].[table]
```

If you upgraded MVC version, the password hash might not be compatible.

Lastly, you should be able to work around it by altering the password requirements in web.config

Comment: Well... Thanks for the input. But the idea is to keep  user passwords as they are...